# Storing iterative function outputs into matrices

Tags: matlab, function, iteration, output

I have an iterative function which gives me two vector outputs. How can I store these outputs into two separate matrices in matlab?

`[A, B]=iterative_function(x,y)`

the size of `A` and `B` varies in every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sizes of the outputs vary, it's best to store them in a [`cell` array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
A_cell = cell(1, num_iter);
B_cell = cell(1, num_iter);
for ii = 1:num_iter
    ...
    [A_cell{ii}, B_cell{ii}] = iterative_function(x, y);
    ...
end
```

where `num_iter` is the number of iterations and `ii` is the loop variable.

Comment: thanks. but only the last iteration values are stored in my matrix.What I might be doing wrong?                                                                                []    []    []    []    [1x3 double]

Comment: @user5916581 what does your `for` loop look like?

Comment: n=length(something);

for ii = 1:n
    A=cell(1,n);
    B=cell(1,n);
    [A{ii}, B{ii}] = function(a, b)
       
end

Comment: @user5916581 `A=cell(1,n); B=cell(1,n); ` have to go before the `for`, otherwise you keep resetting `A` and `B`.

Comment: @user5916581 Do you mean `A=cell(n, 1)`? Check the docs on indexing.